# How to calculate a level with an unlimited number of levels?

Tags: mysql, sql

Now I have that structure (very simplify):

```
promotion:
id | name | level1 | points1| level2 | points2 | client_id
1  | A    | 10     |   12   |   20   | 15      | 1

client:
id | name | value
1  | john |  15
```

And that's how I calculate the level:

```
SELECT 
name,
CASE
    WHEN client.value >= promotion.level2 THEN promotion.points2
    WHEN client.value >= promotion.level1 THEN promotion.points1
    ELSE "None"
END as points
FROM promotion
JOIN client ON client.id = promotion.client_id
```

This is working well, but I would like to have such structure:

```
promotion:
id | name | client_id
1  | A    |    1

level:
id | name   | level | points | promotion_id
1  | level1 | 10    | 12     |  1
2  | level2 | 10    | 15     |  1

client:
id | name | value
1  | john |  15
```

But I don't have any idea how to use it in my query to get points...

```
SELECT 
name,
CASE
    ???
END as points
FROM promotion
JOIN client ON client.id = promotion.client_id
LEFT JOIN level ON promotion.id= level.promotion_id
```

Comment: Amend your schema. A database table is not  a apreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will give you the desired results. It uses a `LEFT JOIN` to find any rows in the `level` table which are lower than the client `value`, and then takes the `MAX` of those values, using `COALESCE` to set the value to `None` if there are no levels below the client's value:

```
SELECT p.name AS promotion,
       c.name AS client,
       COALESCE(MAX(l.points), 'None') AS points
FROM promotion p
JOIN client c ON c.id = p.client_id
LEFT JOIN level l ON l.promotion_id = p.id AND l.level < c.value
GROUP BY p.name, c.name
```

Output for your sample data:

```
promotion   client  points
A           john    12
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/prMq5SjTmgZG8eYoogEXnD/0)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a correlated subquery:

```
select p.name,
       (select l.points
        from level l
        where l.promotion_id = p.points and
              l.level <= c.value
        order by l.level desc
        limit 1
       ) as points
from promotion p join
     client c 
     on c.id = p.client_id;
```

The point of using a correlated subquery is to avoid an aggregation on the full data.  With an index on `level(promotion_id, level, points)`, this should have better performance.